# Passing the result of a subquery as a parameter to PL/SQL package

Tags: sql, oracle

This seems like such a basic question, but I didn't find anything similar on here...

I am currently generating `exec` statements by concatenating various strings and columns like this:

```
SELECT ('exec my_package.my_procedure(input_var1 => ''' || columnA || ''', input_var2 => [... ... ...] || ''');') As sql_stmt FROM myTable;
```

This worked just fine until I decided to add another input parameter that should get its value from a subquery like this (I left out the irrelevant parts, it's the same query as above just with an added parameter):

```
input_var_my_id => (select NVL(MAX(my_id)+1,1) from  someTable where [various conditions] )
```

After I added that parameter, I am getting a `PLS-00103` error, saying that the symbol SELECT was encountered when ( - + case mod new not null [....]
 were expected.

The generated exec statement looks like this:

```
 my_package.my_procedure(input_var1 => 'whatever', input_var_my_id => (select NVL(MAX(my_id)+1,1) from  someTable where [various conditions] ));
```

The subquery itself is valid, if I copy it from the generated statement and execute it, I am getting a single dataset as a result - just as expected.

Is it not possible to pass the result of a subquery as a parameter to a PL/SQL package? Are there any workarounds? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to have a query inside the actual parameter list. You can call some functions directly but only those implemented in PL/SQL. You can't switch to an SQL context. You can see that with a simpler example:

```
exec dbms_output.put_line(select user from dual);

ORA-06550: line 1, column 28:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
...
```

You will have to put the query result into a local variable, which is going to be ugly in your generated code; it needs to end up as:

```
declare
  l_input_var_my_id someTable.my_id%type;
begin
  select NVL(MAX(my_id)+1,1) into l_input_var_my_id from someTable where [various conditions];
  my_package.my_procedure(input_var_my_id => l_input_var_my_id, ...);
end;
```

You can put all of that in an `exec`:

```
exec declare l_input_var_my_id someTable.my_id%type; begin select NVL(MAX(my_id)+1,1) into l_input_var_my_id from someTable where [various conditions];  my_package.my_procedure(input_var_my_id => l_input_var_my_id, ...); end;
```

... and then generate that from your original query.

But as `exec` is just a shorthand for an anonymous block and has to be on one line by default, it might be clearer to generate the block - so have that without the `exec` and with a `/` on a line on its own. Depends how you plan to call the result, and whether it needs to be easy to read.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Still getting the PLS-00103 at the position of the `;` in `exec declare l_input_var_my_id;`. Will try to find a way to solve it

Comment: @daZza - sorry, I forgot to include the data type in the declaration. Updated (though you can use `number` instead of the `%type` syntax if you prefer).

Comment: Just realized this as well, thanks! Getting closer to the end result, though now a `SQL command not properly ended` is occuring, I guess it's a typo or something somewhere in this long exec command. Will check it and hopefully find the culprit. Thanks for your fast help again :)

Comment: Generating a formatted anonymous block (instead of exec on a single line) would make that kind of debugging easier. Maybe you just missed a semicolon, e.g. after the `select ... into` command and before the package call? Just guessing of course. Good luck finding that...

Comment: Checked that first, it's there (unfortunately :D). I stripped the exec command down for debugging purposes and am currently just executing the first part (select into) without the package call after it. Edit: Found it... I am an idiot and changed the postions of `into` and `from`